# SQL Select Into Field

Tags: sql, distinct, select-into

I want to accomplish something of the following:

```
Select DISTINCT(tableA.column) INTO tableB.column FROM tableA
```

The goal would be to select a distinct data set and then insert that data into a specific column of a new table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much there.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column INTO tableB FROM tableA
```

It's going to insert into whatever column(s) are specified in the select list, so you would need to alias your select values if you need to insert into columns of `tableB` that aren't in `tableA`.

[SELECT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT column INTO tableB FROM tableA
```

SELECT INTO will create a table as it inserts new records into it.  If that is not what you want (if tableB already exists), then you will need to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (
column
)
SELECT DISTINCT
column
FROM tableA
```

Remember that if tableb has more columns that just the one, you will need to list the columns you will be inserted into (like I have done in my example).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following...

```
INSERT INTO tableB (column)
Select DISTINCT(tableA.column)
FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

> The goal would be to select a distinct data set and then insert that data into a specific column of a new table.

I don't know what the schema of tableB is... if table B already exists and there is no unique constraint on the column you can do as any of the others suggest here....

`INSERT INTO tableB (column)Select DISTINCT(tableA.column)FROM tableA`

but if you have a unique constraint on table B and it already exists you'll have to exclude those values already in table B...

`INSERT INTO tableB (column)

Select DISTINCT(tableA.column)

FROM tableA 

WHERE tableA.column NOT IN (SELECT /* NOTE */ tableB.column FROM tableB) 

-- NOTE: Remember if there is a unique constraint you don't need the more

-- costly form of a "SELECT DISTICT" in this subquery against tableB

-- This could be done in a number of different ways - this is just 

-- one version.  Best version will depend on size of data in each table, 

-- indexes available, etc.  Always prototype different ways and measure perf.`